# Why i should have been used try-catch?

Tags: java

Good day, 
Why in video lessons one human was not using try-catch, and, if i not be using try-catch i have an error IOException on createnewFile(), FileWriter etc.
Maybe this is easy, i from c++, its big question for me.

Thats my code:
PS. Sorry for "best english"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    File file1 = new File("temp.txt");
    if(!file1.exists()) {
        System.out.println("Creating file...");
        try
        {
            file1.createNewFile();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try
    {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file1);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        out.write("aString");
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file1);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while(in.ready()) {
            System.out.println(in.readLine());
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use "video lessons" or "youtube tutorials". most of them aren't nearly as good as they themselves believe them to be. You don't "have" an IOException (and if you do, you still have them with the try catch). The try catch is merely a way to handle Exceptions. If you don't want to use try-catch, you have to let your add throws IOException to your methods signature.

Comment: Okay, i know that some tutorials have not a good code, but intelij IDEA dont want to work whithout try-cath in this situation. I was include this: import java.io.*;

Comment: this has nothing to do with which IDE you use. if you don't want a try catch there, change your method signature to:
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

but you should also understand why it is nonsense to do so

Comment: But isn't it the same with c++ ? Exception handling using `try-catch` for any method throwing one. Or is it only "unchecked" exception in c++, it's been a while...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use try- catch block to maintain the flow of execution of code.
If exception occurs it goes to catch block and e.printStackTrace it gives us the information why exception occurs and we can handle it here with our logic.
if we dont use try-catch the flow of code is stuck where exception occurs.
So thats why we use try-catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Java requires that you handle **checked exceptions** in your code, either by specifying that your method can throw the exception or by handling it with a try-catch block. If you don't do one of these two at the point where you call a method that may throw a checked exception such as `IOException`, the compiler is going to produce an error.

You can learn about exceptions in Java here: [Lesson: Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) (Oracle Java Tutorials).

Specifically: [The Catch or Specify Requirement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html)